# Problema con un Thread en Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Tengo un programa que utilizo en un restaurante para crear pedidos. Estoy tratando de optimizarlo y he pensado que sería útil realizar con hilos el proceso de crear un pedido.

El código que utilizo en la clase principal es este, que se activa cada vez que presionas un botón:

```
ImprimirPedido imprimir = new ImprimirPedido(parameters, parameters1); imprimir.start();
```

Las variables que le paso al constructor son dos variables Map que se llenan de datos antes de llamar al hilo y funcionan perfectamente porque en la versión que tengo instalada allí va genial.

Dentro de la clase ImprimirPedido está este código:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    
    properties = new ProjectProperties();

    //Finalmente imprimimos el ticket del pedido
    if (properties.isActiveImpresoraBarra().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

        try {

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/Reports/TicketPedido.jasper", parameters, conexion.connectDB());
            metodosAuxiliares.print(print, properties.getImpresoraBarra());

            JasperPrint print1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/Reports/PedidoCocina.jasper", parameters1, conexion.connectDB());
            metodosAuxiliares.print(print1, properties.getImpresoraCocina());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido imprimir el pedido.\n" + ex.getMessage(), "Awsys", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La impresora está deshabilitada. Contacta con un administrador.", "Awsys", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando realizo un pedido, va genial, el hilo imprime por separado de la ejecución principal y agiliza la tarea de la persona que utiliza el software, pero al crear un segundo pedido, me da una excepción como que el informe está vacío.

Lo que no entiendo es por que la primera vez que se hace al iniciar el programa si hace lo que debería pero la segunda vez no lo hace si el hilo lo creo cada vez que se pulsa el botón. ¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: que excepcion sale??

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null range specified
 at javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges.<init>(PageRanges.java:211)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter.exportReport(JRPrintServiceExporter.java:401)
 at Configuracion.MetodosComunes.print(MetodosComunes.java:714)
 at Pedidos.pedidos$24$1$1.run(pedidos.java:849)+